# JS: Can "false" be type-coerced to false?

Tags: javascript, type-coercion

When you use Html5 localStorage values are stored as strings. This is something you need to deal with if you want to store the state of a checkbox and then restore it at a later date. I was hoping that something like this would work:

```
(function() {
  function e(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }

  e('save').addEventListener('click', function() {
   localStorage['check-value'] = e('checkbox').checked
  })
  e('checkbox').checked = localStorage['check-value'];
})();
```

But it seems that 'check-value' will store something along the lines of `"false"` if the box is not checked and the string `"false"` gets type-coerced to `true` on that second-to-last line. I know that I could make a little if-test but this is for a hobby project and I want to figure it out if possible. Can `"false"` be coerced to `false`?

I'm not using libraries for this btw because its a chrome extension and I want to keep it lightweight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"false" is just a string like any other, you would need to do your own check here.

Comment: It differs from "" which is a falsy-value :)

Comment: Indeed, I guess I should have said that 'false" has no special meaning.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `JSON.parse` to pull out the value. Ideally you would also use `JSON.stringify` to serialize objects etc. You can make this more manageable by abstracting it away behind some other interface.

```
JSON.parse("false") == false
```

Example for a wrapper:

```
var LocalStorageManager = new (function () {
   this.set = function (key, object) {
      localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(object);
   };

   this.get = function (key) {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage[key]);
   };
});
```

Comment: I was going to say this could cause issues but a browser that supports localStorage should also support JSON anyway.

Comment: Yeah, had that thought. I think I'd rather not have to invoke JSON.parse that often this is a chrome extension so it would run on every page.

Comment: @George Mauer: Try it out. Unless you have lots of data, it's unlikely the user will even notice whatever small overhead comes from `JSON.parse` and friends.

Comment: So is that being promoted as best practice? Rather than deal with string conversion just store everything in a single json-serialized object and only pull it out of there if you have performance issues?

Comment: @George Mauer: It depends on what values you're storing. If you won't be storing any complex data structures (i.e. you're sticking to primitives like Numbers and Booleans) this is probably overkill and you could do just as well by converting those in the typical fashion. In the end though, personally, I think this solution is much more robust, easier to use, and easier to maintain. Sure, it *might* be a bit slower than some of the other methods, but parsing JSON (and especially simple values like these) is already pretty darn fast.

Comment: @pst: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. Could you expand on this?

Comment: @CD Sanchez Yeah, I'm on board with what you're saying. Might be a good idea for any sizable project to create your own version of localStorage that does this implicitly. Or just add some methods to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can test whether it's equal to the string "false":

```
e('checkbox').checked = localStorage['check-value'] != 'false';
```

Alternatively, you can coerce it to a number before you store it and after you retrieve it:

```
localStorage['check-value'] = +e('checkbox').checked
// ...
e('checkbox').checked = +localStorage['check-value']
```

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of coercing to a number but I don't think your code would work `var str = "false"; +str;` in the console outputs NaN

Comment: It coerces it twice. So before you store it, `false` gets translated to `0`. Then, when you retrieve it, the string `"0"` gets coerced back to a number `0`, which JavaScript turns into `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do that on JS. You should use `var boolValue = (stringValue !== 'false')` or whatever floats your boat.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
e('checkbox').checked = localStorage['check-value'];
```

to this:

```
e('checkbox').checked = localStorage['check-value'] == "true";
```

or depending upon what you want:

```
e('checkbox').checked = localStorage['check-value'] != "false";
```

If you do this more than a couple times, wrap the boolean local storage access in a tiny little function that returns only boolean true or false.

```
function tfStr(val) {
    return(val === "true");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just riffing here but you could do something *really* stupid like

`eval(localStorage['check-value'])`

If the string is false it will evaluate to the boolean false. Obviously you don't want to do that since it's a major security hole.

Alternatively you could use a ternary operator:

`(localStorage['check-value']==="false")?false:localStorage['check-value'];`

Comment: Hmm actually that's interesting - WOULD that be a security hole? I'm not clear on the localStorage rules but it seems like the only thing that goes in there is stuff that code on your domain placed in there. So if malicious code is in localStorage that means it already had a chance to run and do it's damage...am I wrong in this line of reasoning?